# h264 intra4x4 pred mode decoding in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I got confused with the following code in `libavcodec/h264_cavlc.c`
which is a part of h264 decoder of ffmpeg.

```
int ff_h264_decode_mb_cavlc(const H264Context *h, H264SliceContext *sl)
    .
    .
    .
        if(IS_INTRA4x4(mb_type)){
            int i;
            int di = 1;
            if(dct8x8_allowed && get_bits1(&sl->gb)){
                mb_type |= MB_TYPE_8x8DCT;
                di = 4;
            }

//                fill_intra4x4_pred_table(h);
            for(i=0; i<16; i+=di){
                int mode = pred_intra_mode(h, sl, i);

                if(!get_bits1(&sl->gb)){
                    const int rem_mode= get_bits(&sl->gb, 3);
                    mode = rem_mode + (rem_mode >= mode);
                }

                if(di==4)
                    fill_rectangle(&sl->intra4x4_pred_mode_cache[ scan8[i] ], 2, 2, 8, mode, 1);
                else
                    sl->intra4x4_pred_mode_cache[scan8[i]] = mode;
            }
            write_back_intra_pred_mode(h, sl);
            if (ff_h264_check_intra4x4_pred_mode(h, sl) < 0)
                return -1;
        }
```

when `di == 4` it reads only four prediction modes from
the bitstream. I expect to extract 16 pred modes since
we are working on an INTRA4x4 macroblock.

what is the function `fill_rectangle()` doing?

Answer (score 2):

di=4 means we're using a 8x8 DCT for this subblock. You have up to 16 modes only if all subblocks in this macroblock use the 4x4 DCT. If you're using the 8x8 DCT, you can have as little as 4 subblocks per macroblock. Each block can select the 8x8 or 4x4 DCT so you can have 4 (4x DCT8, 0x DCT4), 7 (3x DCT8, 1x 2x2 DCT4), 10, 13 or 16 intra modes coded per macroblock.

For the following 4x4 rectangle of subblocks in a macroblock:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

scan8[] gives the index in a right-bottom aligned 8x5 array, like this:

```
x x x tl t1 t2 t3 t4
x x x l1  a  b  c  d
x x x l2  e  f  g  h
x x x l3  i  j  k  l
x x x l4  m  n  o  p
```

Which allows you to get above/left edges for contextual purposes for prediction of the current block's intra mode. fill_rectangle fills a 2x2 "rectangle" with the same mode, with a stride of 8, e.g. a, b, e and f for the topleft 8x8 DCT block.

For visualization purposes, if the topleft and bottomright block used the 8x8 DCT, the block would essentially use intra prediction mode layouts like this:

```
 A  c d
    g h
i j  K
m n
```